# C# Blazor WebAssembly Cannot Access Closed Stream PDF Creation iText7

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, itext7, memorystream

I am taking a PDF through Blazor, using iText7 to process it in several ways - I wanted to be in a position where I reuse the MemoryStream - rather than converting to a byte[] back to a MemoryStream for each step of the processing.

Create a MemoryStream from a pdf file uploaded by user:

```
Stream stream = pdfFile.OpenReadStream(MAXALLOWEDSIZE);
var msPDF = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(msPDF);
msPDF.Position = 0;
```

Send that MemoryStream to iText to remove text (for example) - this all works fine btw.

```
var (outputPdf, removedPages) = await removeModel.RemoveText(msPDF);
```

outputPdf is a MemoryStream returned by a method that looks like this:

```
public async Task<(MemoryStream, string)> RemoveText(MemoryStream pdfFile)
{
    var outStream = new MemoryStream();
    string result = "";

    using (var pdfIn = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile)))
    {
        using (var pdfOut = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outStream)))
        {
            // do stuff to remove text
            result = doneStuff;
            // Tried this didn't work: return (outStream, result)
            // Also tried: var numberedDoc = Pagination.RepaginatePages(outStream, pageCount);
        }
    }
    return (outStream, result)
}
```

I want to send the returned MemoryStream to another function:

```
byte[] numberedDoc = Pagination.RepaginatePages(outputPdf, pageCount);
```

However, I hit the "Cannot Access Closed Stream" exception.

One more thing I tried was dropping the "using" on the pdfOut and placing the return within the using statement but this made no difference.

```
public async Task<(MemoryStream, string)> RemoveText(MemoryStream pdfFile)
{
    var outStream = new MemoryStream();
    string result = "";

    using (var pdfIn = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile)))
    {
        var pdfOut = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outStream)))
        // do stuff
        result = doneStuff;
        // Also tried: return (outStream, result);
    }
    return (outStream, result)
}
```

Finally, I don't want to put ALL of the processing in a single method, it would be awful.

Is there a way to get the MemoryStream without it being closed - even if I have to send to another method from within the method - that would be better - but I tried that too - and that didn't work either in the way that I tried it.

If it isn't possible, then I will have to take the hit on the byte[] but was hoping to avoid it - but it would be nice to have clarity that it isn't possible.

Comment: Why are you generating a PDF document *on the browser*? Blazor WASM runs on the browser, which has limited resources, no multithreading and no access to the local file system. Single Page Applications like Blazor WASM are *not* meant for heavy duty work like PDF generation

Comment: In any case, a MemoryStream is just a `Stream` wrapper over a `byte[]` buffer. Instead of reusing memory, your code is cloning the same bytes multiple times - from the first pdfFile into the first MemoryStream, from that into the PdfReader and then into the PdfIn document. Then another Pdfdocument is created, I assume based on the original's contents

Comment: The `MemoryStream` grows its buffer the same way a List<> does when it's full, by copying the contents into a new buffer with double the size. Your code could easily be using twice the RAM you assume for every MemoryStream. To avoid this, pass a `capacity` to both `MemoryStream` and `List<>`. This way a buffer with `capacity` items is preallocated

Comment: There are reasons it is done client side - GDPR.  Not really sure how else you can create a PDF other than cloning the MemoryStream - if you have a solution, please do post it.

Comment: As for the error itself, one of those classes disposes its input stream *as it should*. Stream objects aren't meant to be reused, in fact it's part of their contract that trying to use them once they're closed will throw. MemoryStream behaves the same way. If you want to save memory *process the PDFs on the server, not the browser*. You can use array pooling to reuse byte buffers in an application instead of creating a new one very way.

Comment: Finally, you can use [RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) to reuse memory-based streams using buffer pooling

Comment: No, GDPR has absolutely nothing to do with this. GDPR doesn't say `Thou shall nuke thy customer's browser`. You won't escape GDPR by claiming you aren't sending customer data to the server. it's still your application. You're still processing that data. You're still liable for any GDPR violations caused, eg if it emits credit card numbers to the console

Comment: In any case, if you want to reuse memory, use `RecyclableMemoryStream` and be careful about what gets moved around. `pdfFile.OpenReadStream` gave you the only input stream you need. You don't need to copy the contents into browser memory, unless you need to move back in a forward-only stream

Comment: I may be processing the data - but I am not moving it out of the Jurisdiction, which has its own implications.  I will look into the RecyclableMemoryStream thanks for the direction.

Comment: That would only make sense if you build a cloud-hosted multi-tenant service. Otherwise both the browser and server would be the customer's responsibility. That attempt of bypassing GDPR would require not keeping any log data either, not even the tenant ID. Never mind authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PdfDocument` instances have setters

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets, whether
/// <see cref="Close()"/>
/// method shall close associated PdfReader.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="closeReader">
/// true,
/// <see cref="Close()"/>
/// method shall close associated PdfReader, otherwise false.
/// </param>
public virtual void SetCloseReader(bool closeReader)
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets, whether
/// <see cref="Close()"/>
/// method shall close associated PdfWriter.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="closeWriter">
/// true,
/// <see cref="Close()"/>
/// method shall close associated PdfWriter, otherwise false.
/// </param>
public virtual void SetCloseWriter(bool closeWriter)
```

Thus, if you don't want the `outStream` in your

```
var pdfOut = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outStream)))
```

to be closed by iText, call

```
pdfOut.SetCloseWriter(false);
```

as early as possible.

And similarly, if you don't want the `pdfFile` in your

```
var pdfIn = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile))
```

to be closed by iText, call

```
pdfIn.SetCloseReader(false);
```

as early as possible.

---

Alternatively, both `PdfReader` and `PdfWriter` have methods

```
public virtual void SetCloseStream(bool closeStream)
```

Thus, you can also call

```
pdfOut.GetWriter().SetCloseStream(false);
pdfIn.GetReader().SetCloseStream(false);
```

to keep the stream arguments open.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that around before, but was a bit concerned about them remaining open - also it worked but left me with a 0 byte product at the end of it - which I might have been able to fix in time.  I have now bitten the bullet and just put the processes within the same method so there is just one memory stream. Annoying, but not the end of the world as a lot of the code was repetitive anyway.